# How to get a value of input in Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, input

I am trying to get a value of input that i have declareted inside the render method, but when i get the element by id (or other methods) i don't have the field value.

Actually, i am using this function for get the value:

*"document.getElementById("inputUser")"*

Too, i have tried add *".value"*, but this function dont recognise how a valid and it doesn´t compile.

When i depured with the console of the browser i cant access to this value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the value with document.getElementById("...")["value"]